# How to remove IDs from SEF URL in Joomla?

Tags: component, development, url, sef, jroute

I 'm writing a custom component and I already get done the router.php:

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
function empresaBuildRoute(&$query) //Esta función divide la url y se trae las variables.
{
    $segments = array();
    if (isset($query['view']))
    {
        $segments[] = $query['view'];
        unset($query['view']);
    }
    if (isset($query['padre']))
    {
        $segments[] = $query['padre'];
        unset($query['padre']);
    };
    if (isset($query['id']))
    {
        $segments[] = $query['id'];
        unset($query['id']);
    };
    if (isset($query['categoria']))
    {
        $segments[] = $query['categoria'];
        unset($query['categoria']);
    };
    if (isset($query['empresa']))
    {
        $segments[] = $query['empresa'];
        unset($query['empresa']);
    };

    return $segments;
}
function empresaParseRoute($segments) //Esta función reconoce las variables y las reacomoda.
{   

    //print_r($segments); //Si deseas verificar el contenido de la Array "segments".

    $vars = array();
    switch($segments[0])
    {
        case 'actividad': //Verifica las View y según cada una del componente, ordena las variables.
            $vars['view'] = 'actividad';
            $id = explode(':', $segments[2]); //Los segmentos son una array que contiene otra array
            $vars['id'] = (int) $id[0]; //La posicion 0 de la array contenida en la posicion 2 de la array anterior
        break;

        case 'empresa':
            $vars['view'] = 'empresa';
            print_r($segments);
            $categoria = explode(':', $segments[1]);
            $vars['categoria'] = (int) $categoria[0];
            $empresa = explode(':', $segments[2]);
            $vars['empresa'] = (int) $empresa[0];
        break;
    }
    return $vars;
}
```

It does its job but the url looks like

> /actividad/10-hosteleria-y-restaurantes/11-cervecerias

I read a lot but there's just information for remove ID in articles (that's old, joomla 3.x do this by default), nothing about this. Can some one help me with this?

Comment: As far as I understand, you should NOT push `id` into `$segments` array. So `$segments[] = $query['id'];` should be removed from your `build()` function. Also you need to find the `id` from the `alias` by writing some db queries inside your `parse()` function. eg: `$vars['id'] = get_id_from_alias($alias)` where `$alias` is a member of `$segments` array say `$segments[0]` that is defined inside your `build()` function.

Comment: I was thinking in something like this. Now you enlighten me a lot. If this is the solution i'll post it here.

Comment: @Farahmand, thank you, i find the solution, i'll post it here.

Comment: You're welcome @Ignacio! Glad it helped!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution with the help of **[@Farahmand](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/users/1520/farahmand)**, here it is:

```
<?php

defined('_JEXEC') or die;
function empresaBuildRoute(&$query) //Esta función divide la url y se trae las variables.
{
    $segments = array();

    if (isset($query['view']))
    {
        $segments[] = $query['view'];
        unset($query['view']);
    }
    if (isset($query['padre']))
    {
        $segments[] = $query['padre'];
        unset($query['padre']);
    };
    if (isset($query['id']))
    {
        $segments[] = $query['id'];
        unset($query['id']);
    };
    if (isset($query['categoria']))
    {   
        $cat = explode(':', $query['categoria']); //Variable temporal para guardar solo el alias de la categoria
        if (count($cat) == 2) { //Contar los valores, si son dos es porque existe ID y Alias
            $segments[] = $cat[1];
        } else { //Caso contrario, seleccionar la categoría pues esta contendría solo el ID
            $segments[] = $query['categoria'];
        }
        unset($query['categoria']);
    };

    if (isset($query['empresa']))
    {
        $segments[] = $query['empresa'];
        unset($query['empresa']);
    };
    return $segments;
}

function empresaParseRoute($segments) //Esta función reconoce las variables y las reacomoda.
{   

    print_r($segments); //Si deseas verificar el contenido de la Array "segments".
    $vars = array();
    switch($segments[0])
    {

        case 'actividad': //Verifica las View y según cada una del componente, ordena las variables.
        $vars['view'] = 'actividad';
            $id = explode(':', $segments[2]); //Los segmentos son una array que contiene otra array
            $vars['id'] = (int) $id[0]; //La posicion 0 de la array contenida en la posicion 2 de la array anterior
            break;

        case 'empresa':
            $vars['view'] = 'empresa';

            $db = JFactory::getDbo();
            $query = $db->getQuery(true);
            $query->select('id');
            $query->from($db->quoteName('#__categories'));
            $query->where($db->quoteName('alias')." = ".$db->quote($segments[1]));

            $db->setQuery($query);
            $result = $db->loadResult();

            $vars['categoria'] = (int) $result;

            $empresa_alias = str_replace(":","-",$segments[2]);
            $db = JFactory::getDbo();
            $query = $db->getQuery(true);
            $query->select('id');
            $query->from($db->quoteName('#__viviren_empresa'));
            $query->where($db->quoteName('alias')." = ".$db->quote($empresa_alias));

            $db->setQuery($query);
            $empresa = $db->loadResult();

            $vars['empresa'] = (int) $empresa;
        break;
    }
    return $vars;
}
?>
```

1. Building the route I wrote a temporal variable to explode the query
   by ':' called **$cat**. If the query have a Slug, the explode will make an array like this: `array([0]=> id, [1]=> alias)` else will be `array([0]=> id)`
2. Next I make a conditional with a count to know if the array has actually an **id** and an **alias**: `if (count($cat) == 2) {` if this is true it will fill the segment with only the alias content inside of **$cat[1]**: `$segments[] = $cat[1];` else it will fill with **$query['categoria']**: `else { $segments[] = $query['categoria']; }`
3. Inside the **parse()** in the case 'empresa', wich is my view, I made a DB call for information where I try to find the id when the alias is the listed one inside of **$segments[1]**:

`$db = JFactory::getDbo();
      $query = $db->getQuery(true);
      $query->select('id');
      $query->from($db->quoteName('#__categories'));
      $query->where($db->quoteName('alias')." = ".$db->quote($segments[1]));
      $db->setQuery($query);
    $result = $db->loadResult();`

And store that inside of **$vars['categoria']** : `$vars['categoria'] = (int) $result;` for the category id.

4. For the "empresa" id I find (and I don't know why) that BuildRoute() or ParseRoute() changes the first "-" in an alias for a ":" and broke the DataBase call. To fix this i wrote `$empresa_alias = str_replace(":","-",$segments[2]);` then **instead** of use the **$segments[1]** I used the **$empresa_alias** variable.
5. Finally the url now looks like `...com/actividades/empresa/cervecerias/
   cerveceria-madriz-cafeteria` without id in "cervecerias". I'll repeat the same with the rest of my views. - http://pinto.isalcedo.com/actividades/empresa/cervecerias/cerveceria-madriz-cafeteria

Sorry for my english and I hope this can help a lot o people.

Answer (score 0):

Create a menu item for any items you don't want to have an ID shown, at the very least a menu item for the parent category `/actividad/10-hosteleria-y-restaurantes` in your example then the alias (used to generate the URL) can be set to whatever you want.

Comment: Oh boy, there is so many categories and so many bussiness inside each category... Also the client (the owner of the site) can't handle that. There is not a code solution?

Comment: @IgnacioSalcedo As far as I know, there is no 'obvious' solution. This has been the single biggest grip as if you want URLs without IDs; the only was seems to be adding them to Menus!

Comment: Sorry, I was not trying to be a douchebag, really sorry if sound like that. I'm doing now some hardcoding, thinking on maybe a .htaccess solution, adding menus is not the solution in this case... I'll update if i find a solution.